# Powershell if file is different then do something

Tags: powershell, file, if-statement, compare

As the title suggests, how do I do an if statement for comparing 2 files? This is what I have so far but even though the files are the same it still keeps prompting me for an update

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName 'PresentationFramework'

$continue = 'Yes'
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://<url>/file" -OutFile "C:\temp\file"
if ( "C:\temp\file" -ne "C:\app\file" ) {
    $caption = "Update Available!"    
    $message = "There is a new version available. Do you want to update to the latest version?"

    $continue = [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show($message, $caption, 'YesNo');
} else {
    Write-Output "You have the latest version!"
}

if ($continue -eq 'Yes') {
    Write-Output "Downloading application Please wait..."
    // Do something //
} else {
    Write-Output "Cancelled"
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

Comment: currently you compare two strings (filepath) that do not match. you want to compare the content and not the filepath. you can do:
```If (compare-object (gc "C:\temp\file") (gc "C:\app\file")){}``` It will enter the expression if differences were found

Answer (score 1):

This is the logic I would personally follow, you can re-estructure it later for your need but in very basic steps:

1. Get the MD5 sum of my current file.
2. Query the new file with `Invoke-WebRequest` and using a [`MemoryStream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.memorystream.-ctor?view=net-6.0) check if the new hash is the same as the previous one.
3. If it's not, write that stream to a [`FileStream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream?view=net-6.0).

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

try {
    $previousFile = "C:\app\file"
    $previousHash = (Get-FileHash $previousFile -Algorithm MD5).Hash

    $webReq    = Invoke-WebRequest 'https://<url>/file'
    $memStream = [IO.MemoryStream] $webReq.Content
    $newHash   = (Get-FileHash -InputStream $memStream -Algorithm MD5).Hash

    if($previousHash -ne $newHash) {
        $file = [IO.File]::Create('path\to\mynewfile.ext')
        $memStream.WriteTo($file)
    }
}
finally {
    $file, $memStream | ForEach-Object Dispose
}
```

The main idea behind it is to check all in memory so as to avoid the need to download a file if not needed.

Comment: Nice! As an optimization, you might first do a `$webReq = Invoke-WebRequest 'https://<url>/file' -Method Head` to get headers only and compare `$webReq.Headers.'Content-Length'` (if available) with the size of the file on disk. If they are different, then skip download and hash calculations.

Comment: @zett42 fair point but I believe that's up to OP to determine since we don't have information on this

Comment: I think the only issue could be if the server returns incorrect `Content-Length`, in which case the file would always be downloaded. Comparing the hash values in any cases except when the `Content-Length` _equals_ the file size on disk would propably be the most robust way to deal with such bad header data.

Comment: @zett42 I would personally rely on hash comparison only however I think it's worth noting that checking the content length in headers is also an option. You should add it as answer since you came up with it. OP might want to combine both options in one script